# SQL Query help please

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am putting together a complex query to create a sort of report, and having a little trouble. I need to have the report show only accounts 9000-9200. The report is to display each account [Bill Acct], then have totals for that account for each hour, and then finish up with a current total for the day for that account. My current query is below:

```
Select [Bill Acct], 
    (select [Total Fee] from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 0 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0000],
    (select [Total Fee] from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 1 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0100],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 2 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0200],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 3 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0300],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 4 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0400],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 5 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0500],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 6 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0600],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 7 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0700],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 8 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0800],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 9 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [0900],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 10 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as [1000],
    (select Sum([Total Fee]) from Trans where Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) as Total
From Trans
Where [Bill Acct] between 9000 and 9200
ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)
And Void = 0
Group By  [Bill Acct], [Site Code]
Order by [Site Code]
```

Comment: So where is the problem ?

Comment: Using the above query, I am getting the total for all accounts for that hour, and cannot figure out how to get the total for each account for the hour.

Comment: At the very least, you're missing an aggregate function on the second and third columns.  I'd also think you would want to include [Site Code] in the select clause -- since you're grouping on it.  More fundamentally, this is a very inefficient query.  Why not group by DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) and then pivot the results to get your columns?  That would eliminate all those subqueries.  You would need to union the total also, but it is well worth it.

Comment: No offense but your query looks weird.

Comment: I realize it does, AHiggins got what I was trying to do, his gets me the results I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are much better ways to write your query: a PIVOT statement, or a set of CASE statements like below, would be much faster.  There are some missing aggregate functions, as Greenspark mentioned, and you don't have the Site Code field in your SELECT statement.

Assuming that one, all, or some of these are an issue, try the following:

```
SELECT  
    [Bill Acct], 
    [Site Code],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 0 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0000],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 1 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0100],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 2 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0200],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 3 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0300],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 4 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0400],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 5 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0500],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 6 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0600],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 7 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0700],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 8 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0800],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 9 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [0900],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) = 10 THEN [Total Fee] ELSE 0 END) AS [1000],
    SUM([Total Fee]) AS Total
FROM Trans
WHERE 
    ([Bill Acct] BETWEEN 9000 AND 9200) AND
    CAST([Date Out] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND
    Void = 0
GROUP BY [Bill Acct], [Site Code]
ORDER BY [Site Code]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am looking into a creating a pivot Statement, but for the time being, yours works fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correct, your above query can be simplified to something like below

```
Select [Bill Acct], 
    [Total Fee],
    Sum([Total Fee])
 from Trans 
where DATEPART(hh, [Time Out]) in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
 ANd Cast([Date Out] as date) = Cast(getdate() as date)) 
 AND [Bill Acct] between 9000 and 9200
And Void = 0
Group By  [Bill Acct], [Total Fee]
Order by [Site Code]
```

Comment: AHiggins fixed it for me, i see what I did wrong now, thank you though!